# Unexpected token, expected "=>" in React Native

Tags: react-native, arrow-functions

I am new to React Native, and so am not familiar with the usage of Arrow Function.
I am trying out this code to get wifi permission.

**My code**

```
import { PermissionsAndroid } from "react-native";

async componentDidMount() {
  await this.askForUserPermission();
}

async askForUserPermission()
{
  try{
    const granted = await PermissionsAndroid.request(
      PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
      {
        title: "Wifi Networks",
        message: "We need your permission to access wifi networks"
      }
    );
    if (granted === PermissionsAndroid.RESULTS.GRANTED){
      console.log("Thank you for your permission! :)");
    }
    else{
      console.log("You will not be able to retrieve wifi networks list");
    }
  }
  catch (err)
  {
    console.warn(err);
  }
}
```

Please Help me Out.

Comment: you need to post the error you got, take a screenshot of the error it throws

Answer (score 1):

It's expecting componentDidMount() to be inside of as class.
Something similar to this would work.

```
class someComponent extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    return this.askForUserPermission();
  }

  async askForUserPermission() {
    // Other code abbreviated.
  }
};

export default someComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to another answer:

the compiler basically ask you to put `=>` because when you are creating a standalone function (not in class) it expect either one of this:

```js
async function myFunction(){
  // implementations...
}

myFunction = async () =>{
  // implementations...
}
```

Unless, you define those functions inside a class component so they will be defined as instances of that class (i.e. no need to add `function` keyword to it)